# Using jQuery to change text upon page load without it being obvious to the user

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that has a lot of stuff going on (lots of content, ads, etc.). For reasons I won't get into, the H2 tag (has a class of "top-story") needs to be replaced. Let's say it comes in hardcoded from the server (which we have no control over) and the H2 title says "zimmerman." We are using jQuery to replace "zimmerman" with "Bob Zimmerman" for example. The problem is, the H2 tag shows "zimmerman" for a moment before it gets changed.

Now, the code used to not even be within the usual $(document).ready() function, and it worked but with some recent code changes I've made, that wasn't working right (and technically it's not reliable anyway, if you don't use the ready func).

Is there some way I can make sure that the user won't see the old text before it's replaced dynamically? Again, this is HTML code that is generated by a server we have no control over, so I can't change what it's outputting.

EDIT: Ok wait. I just learned why the document.ready wasn't there. Here's the deal, there are multiple H2s with the top-story class. The code was RIGHT underneath the very first top-story without a document.ready, which means it would execute as soon as that particular H2 was rendered. I didn't know that's how that worked. I'm going to try something now and see if this works...

EDIT2: I fixed my own problem. The solution was to remove the $(document).ready() and just make sure the script code is right below the H2 it needs to work on. And of course there are multiple H2 tags so I limit it to just the first one:

```
var titleReplacements = [
  ['oldtext', 'New Text!'],
  ['quickhits', 'Quick Hits'],
];

$.each(titleReplacements, function(i, obj) {
    var newText = $('.top-story:first').text().replace(obj[0], obj[1]);
    $('.top-story:first').text(newText);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. The solution was to remove the $(document).ready() and just make sure the script code is right below the H2 it needs to work on. (see EDIT2 above)

Answer (score 3):

Hide the `h2` with CSS

```
h2.top-story { display: none; }
```

and then show it with javascript once it's ready

```
$("h2.top-story").text("Bob Zimmerman").show();
```